# Change the alignment of the content of a Label in Ipywidget

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am using a `ipywidgets.Label` to display a text in a notebook.
Basic question, how do I change the text alignment within the `Label`? It seems to be left aligned and I want it to be right aligned. I really looked for it in the docs but I cannot find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The answer by RZin sort-of works but, it doesn't actually align the text-- it just moves the box containing the text.

One can align the label text this way:

`Label("LABEL", layout=Layout(display="flex", justify_content="flex-start")`

Use `"flex-start"` for left-align, `"center"` for center-align, and `"flex-end"` for right-align. There is [also `"space-between"` and `"space-around"`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#justify-content).

Full example that can be copy and pasted into a notebook:

```py
from ipywidgets import Label, Layout, HBox
from IPython.display import display

x = Label("Align Left", layout=Layout(display="flex", justify_content="flex-start", width="30%", border="solid"))
y = Label("Align Center", layout=Layout(display="flex", justify_content="center", width="30%", border="solid"))
z = Label("Align Right", layout=Layout(display="flex", justify_content="flex-end", width="30%", border="solid"))
display(HBox([x,y,z]))
```

[image: jupyter notebook example output]

Comment: Underrated answer. :D

Answer (score 4):

I had similar question and wrapped my Label with VBox widget.

```
from ipywidgets import VBox, Label, Layout

VBox([Label('I want this to be in the center.')]
,layout=Layout(width='100%', display='flex' ,
align_items='center'))
```